# Docusign Document Encrypt and decrypt using query parameters encrypt set to true in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

In docusign while downloading documents using getDocuments API and when we want to set encrypt to true, it says NO_SECUITY_APPLIANCE_CONFIGURED for this account. How to configure/enable security appliance for docusign's account?
NOTE: Though all docusign's API's are TLS/SSL enabled, I still want to encrypt and decrypt documents

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable the GetDocuments Encryption parameters, you'll need a DocuSign Security Appliance: An on-prem device that holds your encryption keys within your network.

More information on that is available here: https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances

Contact Sales if you're interested in moving forward in that direction.